# Use of if command in awk whithout entering new line

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk

When I run this command:

```
awk '{  if(substr($1,6,2)=="09") { print "Sep";}   }' myfile.log
```

results appear on the screen.

But if I run:

```
awk '{ print $2 "--"   if(substr($1,6,2)=="09") { print "Sep";}   }' myfile.log
```

I receive:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near if

awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because you need to separate print statement and if statement with a `;` semi colon like below. Which tells `awk` that print statement is completed now and `if` statement is going to start, this is syntax of `awk`.

```
awk '{ print $2 "--";if(substr($1,6,2)=="09") { print "Sep" } }' myfile.log
```

But in case you are using non-one liner form of solution then we need not to use `;` specifically because they are separated by new line like following:

```
awk '
{
print $2 "--"
if(substr($1,6,2)=="09") { print "Sep" }
}' myfile.log
```

***NOTE:*** I also removed `;` after your print statement inside your condition block `"Sep" ;` we may only need it when we are using some other Logic after printing things which we are not using as of now.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. But now I have a new problem. The command above works, but inserts new line when displaying "Sep". How can I avoid it?

Comment: @A.Sim, could you please try following, `awk '{printf("%s",$2 "--");if(substr($1,6,2)=="09"){printf("%s\n" "Sep")}}' myfile.log` lso you could update your question with this detail too, this was not given in your question, thank you cheers. Thanks to Ed sir for finding typo in my previous comment, cheers.